How to get rust-analyzer to find definition of hashbrown from the standard library in VS Code?
When developing my simple crate in VS Code with rust-analyzer (v0.3.2037):
[package]
name = "world_hello"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]

use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let _ = HashMap::<i32, i32>::new();
    println!("Hello, world!")
}

I can jump into the definition for HashMap:
...
use hashbrown::hash_map as base;
...

pub struct HashMap<K, V, S = RandomState> {
    base: base::HashMap<K, V, S>,
}

But when I try to jump to the definition of base or hashbrown it says "No definition found":

This is my current Rust version (from rustup show):
Default host: x86_64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/bytedance/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-2023-12-28-x86_64-apple-darwin
nightly-2024-01-26-x86_64-apple-darwin
nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.77.2 (25ef9e3d8 2024-04-09)

I have tried using different versions of rust-analyzer but none of them seem to work. How to solve this?

How did you install Rust? If you used rustup, have you installed rust-src component as well? Please show output of rustup component list --installed.

@AleksanderKrauze
cargo-x86_64-apple-darwin
clippy-x86_64-apple-darwin
rust-docs-x86_64-apple-darwin
rust-src
rust-std-x86_64-apple-darwin
rustc-x86_64-apple-darwin
rustfmt-x86_64-apple-darwin


This problem has been solved in this issue:

You will have to enable the "rust-analyzer.cargo.sysrootQueryMetadata": true, config for this to work, but note that this means [rust-analyzer] will create and delete a lockfile in your toolchain's sysroot when you start a rust-analyze session. This is due to shortcoming in cargo

